# Почему не работает partition в quick sort?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, golang

Пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм быстрой сортировки, на уровне идеи я понял что нужно, а вот с имплементацией у меня возникли проблемы, и я уже очень долгое время не могу понять в чем причина. В итоге взял реализацию разбиения элементов массива относительно опорного с википедии. В чем ошибка? можно на словах, писал на go:

```
func swap(mas_pointer *[]float64, pos1, pos2 int) {
    mas := *mas_pointer
    tmp := mas[pos1]
    mas[pos1] = mas[pos2]
    mas[pos2] = tmp
}

    func partition(mas_pointer *[]float64, lo, hi int) int{
      mas := *mas_pointer
      midl := mas[(lo + hi) / 2]
      fmt.Println(midl)
      fmt.Println(mas)
      i := lo
      j := hi

      for (i <= j) {
        for (mas[i] < midl) {
          i++
        }
        for (mas[j] > midl) {
          j--
        }
        if i <= j{
              swap(&mas, i, j)
              i++
              j--
            }
              // break
              fmt.Println(mas)
      }
      midl = mas[(lo + hi) / 2]
      fmt.Println(midl)
      return j
    }

    func main() {
      mas := []float64{4, 9, 6, 7, 2, 3, 8}
      k := partition(&mas, 0, len(mas) - 1)
      fmt.Println(k, mas)
    }
    >>>  [4 3 6 2 7 9 8]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/J5Un65GVfE

Comment: В целом partition выглядит хорошо, а в чём проблемы? Как оно не работает? Ошибку какую-то выдаёт или неверно сортирует?

Comment: Например я вижу что ответ правильный, оно выбрало средний элемент 7 и относительно его сделало partition, слева все элементы < 7 справа > 7 а по центру = 7. Т.е. всё верно. Может вы хотели чтобы оно сделало полную сортировку, тогда нужно в конце функции partition рекурсивно вызывать её для < и > участка.

Comment: нет, я именно имел ввиду относительно опорного элемента, вот пример пошире
вход:
mas := []float64{22, 21, 419, 11, 0, 25, 22, 33, 100, 1, 0, 12}
выход:
[22 21 12 11 0 0 22 1 100 33 25 419]
опорный элемент 25, но слева от него занчения 33 и 100

Comment: А... Да, действительно, значит алгоритм в википедии не верный, можете попробовать из [англоязычной википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), может он верный.

Comment: Нужно пошагово пройти и подумать.

Comment: После 1 обмена не может такой выход быть. Только такой
{22, 21, 12, 11, 0, 25, 22, 33, 100, 1, 0, 419}

Comment: @Артур Кстати я дописал из Википедии ещё функцию quicksort и всё в целом правильно сортирует, [тут можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NQGR/0). Я понял в чём суть, суть алгоритма partition не в том чтобы слева < по центру = справа > а в том чтобы слева <= справа >=, оно так и делает и этого достаточно для сортировки.

Comment: Да действительно у вас полный алгоритм работает...тогда я ничего не понимаю, я думал оно слева от относительно опорного элемента устанавливает все что меньше его, справа все что больше, а затем 2 эти части заново прогоняются в массиве, но как это возможно если в левой части получаются элементы больше опорного

Comment: @Артур partition вот что делает, он разбивает массив на две части, первая <=  midl а правая >=, этого вполне достаточно для сортировки. Рассмотрим ваш пример `{22, 21, 419, 11, 0, 25, 22, 33, 100, 1, 0, 12}` - он даёт после partition выход `[22 21 12 11 0 0 22 1 100 33 25 419]` и возвращает индекс 8, индекс означает что для индексов < 8 получаем <= midl, для индексов >= 8 получаем >= midl, так и есть по ответу. Кстати у вас ошибка, нужно в partition возвращать `i` а не `j`, чтобы быть в согласии с википедией.

Comment: Ааааааа спасибо большое! я немного по-другому рассуждал, в такой интерпритации все верно

Answer (score 2):

Как понимаю partition был написан на основе алгоритма [из этой статьи Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Алгоритм верный, суть его в том что он входной массив разбивает на две части относительно midl (pivot) элемента, левую и правую, левая содержит элементы <= midl, правая >= midl. Для сортировки потом просто нужно рекурсивно каждую из этих частей также прогнать через partition.

Кстати у вас в коде partition нужно возвращать `i` а не `j` чтобы точно соответствовать википедии. Результат такой после partition что для индексов < i будут элементы <= midl, а для индексов >= i будут элементы >= midl. Вот я дополнил ваш алгоритм до полной сортировки, [можно посмотреть тут онлайн](https://repl.it/NQGR/3).